# Convert English statements to logical forms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Everyone has a roommate who dislikes everyone

- $ R(x,y)=$ $x$ and $y$ are roommates
- $L(x,y)=$ $x$ likes $y$

so it becomes

$$\forall x \exists y (R(x,y) \land \lnot L(y,x))$$

Is this correct ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you have written is that everyone has a roommate who dislikes them.  You used $x$ twice, once for the person who has a roommate and once for the disliked person.  The second "everyone" is everyone in the world, not just one of the roommates.

The correct answer is 
$$\forall x \exists y \forall z (R(x,y) \land \lnot L(y,z))$$

Comment: I think the 'who dislikes everyone' part is ill-defined. Anyway, your interpretation seems sensible.

Comment: Why that for all x not cover everyone ?

Comment: Let us consider a person A, who rooms only with B.  As I read the sentence, B dislikes everyone.  That includes disliking A, but is not limited to it.  B must also dislike me to dislike everyone.

Comment: Yes i understand that but i am asking why the (for all ) in beginning,  not cover everyone including roommate.

Comment: Because you used $x$ for the first roommate already.  If you reuse $x$ later in the sentence it refers to the same person as the first time.

Comment: ok thank you.....

Comment: I posted the correct answer.  See how it compares.  In it $x$ and $z$ can be different people.

Comment: @RossMillikan P(x) doesnot have z then $\forall z P(x)$ and $\exists z P(x)$ are true ?? Is this why you have got forall z outside the whole bracket ?

Comment: You could move the $\forall z$ inside in front of the $\lnot L(y,z)$ if you like.  That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. Your statement reads something like

> “Everyone has a roommate who dislikes him/her.”

You might fix your statement by replacing $\neg L(y,x)$, which reads “$y$ dislikes $x$,” with $\forall z \neg L(y,z)$, which reads “$y$ dislikes everyone.”

---

Not to get nitpicky, but something about this problem bothers me: it assumes that $\neg L(x,y)$ reads “$x$ dislikes $y$,” when, in reality, “not liking someone” is not necessarily the same as “disliking” them. However, this is just a semantic point and not wholly relevant.

Comment: L(x,y) and its negation has been assumed in the book this way